# Bulkindexing JPA Entities modified during Spring transaction to Elasticsearch index

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an JPA Entity Class that is also an Elasticsearch Document. The enviroment is a Spring Boot Application using Spring Data Jpa and Spring Data Elasticsearch.

```
@Entity
@Document(indexname...etc)
@EntityListeners(MyJpaEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
    //ID, constructor and stuff following here
}
```

When an instance of this Entity gets created, updated or deleted it gets reindexed to Elasticsearch. This is currently achieved with an JPA EntityListener which reacts on PostPersist, PostUpdate and PostRemove events.

```
public class MyJpaEntityListener {

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    public void postPersistOrUpdate(MyEntity entity) {
        //Elasticsearch indexing code gets here
    }

    @PostRemove
    public void postPersistOrUpdate(MyEntity entity) {
        //Elasticsearch indexing code gets here
    }
}
```

That´s all working fine at the moment when a single or a few entities get modified during a single transaction. Each modification triggers a separate index operation. But if a lot of entities get modified inside a transaction it is getting slow.

I would like to bulkindex all entities that got modified at the end (or after commit) of a transaction. I took a look at TransactionalEventListeners, AOP and TransactionSynchronizationManager but wasn´t able to come up with a good setup till now.

How can I collect all modified entities per transaction in an elegant way without doing it per hand in every service method myself?

And how can I trigger a bulkindex at the end of a transaction with the collected entities of this transaction.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

One different and in my opinion elegant approach, as you don't mix your services and entities with elasticsearch related code, is to use spring aspects with  @AfterReturning in the service layer transactional methods.

The [pointcut expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts) can be adjusted to catch all the service methods you want.

@Order(1) guaranties that this code will run after the transaction commit.

The code below is just a sample...you have to adapt it to work with your project.

```
@Aspect
@Component()
@Order(1)
public class StoreDataToElasticAspect {

    @Autowired
    private SampleElasticsearhRepository elasticsearchRepository;


    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.example.DatabaseService.bulkInsert(..))")
    public void synonymsInserted(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        //create elasticsearch documents from method params.
        //can also inject database services if more information is needed for the documents.
        List<String> ids = (List) args[0];
        //create batch from ids
       elasticsearchRepository.save(batch);
    }
}
```

And here is an [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/aspectj-after-returning-annotation-example/) with a logging aspect.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I doubt I will be able to create logic that can get all the  entities from the different method parameters in the different services. For example a method that deletes all entities with a certain value in field X. These entities will be gone. The idea to use an aspect to trigger the save is good in my opinion. My problem with it was how to get the entities into the aspect. I pondered the idea to implement a method annotated with @TransactionalEventListener and publish an according event in the JpaEventListener.

Comment: You can adjust your delete method with findBy to get the Ids and then deleteByIds in your service method. This way you''ll have the ids as method parameters.I think that even if you use a deleteBySomtething Spring Data method it internally goes through CrudRepository#delete and loads the entities afterall..so don't expect any performance loss anyway. In our implementation we also store the database id in related  elasticsearch documents. It turned out this is helpful in a bunch of different cases. One of them is that you are able to easily delete the documents you want.